# Function to return two types in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have library and I've added typescript definition type and I'm testing if it's correct. I have two functions: `set_prompt` and `get_prompt` first function accept string and function and I want to use return value of `get_prompt` to be function or string:

I have code like this:

```
var fn: (cb: (prompt: string) => void) => void =  term.get_prompt();
var prompt: string = term.get_prompt();
```

and it throw error on second code

my d.ts file have code like this:

```
declare namespace JQueryTerminal {
    type setStringFunction = (value: string) => void;
    type ExtendedPrompt = ((this: JQueryTerminal, setPrompt: setStringFunction) => (void | PromiseLike<string>));
}
interface JQueryTerminal<TElement = HTMLElement> extends JQuery<TElement> {
    set_prompt(prompt: JQueryTerminal.ExtendedPrompt | string): JQueryTerminal;
    get_prompt(): JQueryTerminal.ExtendedPrompt;
    get_prompt(): string;
}
```

my first code had `| string` at the end of `ExtendedPrompt` and but that was throwing two errors.

Is it possible to use return value of a function with two different types?

I've tried with generics:

```
get_prompt<T = string>(): T;
```

but it will work for any type, is it possible to restrict type to string and `JQueryTerminal.ExtendedPrompt`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're searching for this:

```
function get_prompt<T extends (JQueryTerminal.ExtendedPrompt | string)  = string>(): T;
```

Comment: i thought that `extends` works only with classes and I've didn't tested this with function and base types. thanks.

Comment: AFAIK a `class` is only a way to describe a type. And `extends` should work on all types